# How do I make a simple makefile for gcc on Linux

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have tow  files: `mycode.c` and `mycode.h`

gcc -o mycode  mycode.c  `pkg-config --cflags --libs libstrophe` -lpthread
I need to compile this on Linux using gcc compile with the commende line `gcc -o mycode mycode.c pkg-config --cflags --libs libstrophe -lpthread`

Answer (score 3):

Makefile syntax consists of a few patterns

```
{thing}{colon} {dependencies ...}
<tab>{command}
```

Some things to watch out for:

- Make sure your command generates your {thing}
- Make sure all commands start with a <kbd>TAB</kbd>
- Make sure all your dependencies are files on disk, try to keep them up-to-date and complete
- Each command is ran in its own shell
- A blank line breaks the pattern

There's more but this will get you started

Here is your requested Makefile

```
mycode.o: mycode.c mycode.h
<tab>gcc `pkg-config --cflags libstrophe` -c mycode.c

mycode: mycode.o
<tab>gcc -o mycode `pkg-config --cflags --libs libstrophe` -lpthread mycode.o
```

Note you don't type `<tab>` literally, instead replace that with the tab character.

Comment: I think you are missing a closing back-tick  on the command for making `mycode`.   Also, I think `pkg-config --cflags libstrophe` needs to me moved to the recipe for `mycode.o` as this should provide the include paths.  We can leave `pkg-config --libs libstrophe` in the recipe for `mycode`

Comment: @thurizas Thank you!  I really appreciate it!  Hopefully my changes incorporated your suggestions without additional mistakes.